# Programmatically generating a list of columns to be assigned to data.table with `:=` syntax

Tags: r, data.table

In `data.table`, I can generate a list of new columns that are immediately assigned to the table using the `` `:=` `` syntax, like so:

```
x <- data.table(x1=1:5, x2=1:5)
x[, `:=` (x3=x1+2, x4=x2*3)]
```

Alternatively, I could have done the following:

```
x[, c("x3","x4") := list(x1+2, x2*3)]
```

I would like to do something like the first method, but have the right hand side of the assignment statement be built up automatically using a custom function. For example, suppose I want a function that will accept a set of column names, then generate new columns that are the mean of the given columns, with the column name being equal to the original column plus some suffix. For example,

```
x[, `:=` MEAN(x1,x2)]
```

would yield the same result as

```
x[, `:=` (x1_mean=mean(x1), x2_mean=mean(x2))]
```

Is this possible in `data.table`? I realize this is possible if I'm willing to pass in a list of column names like in the `c("x3","x4") := ...` example, but I want to avoid this so I don't have to write as much code.

Comment: I would start with checking (pseudo code inside `""`) `f <- function(cols) pryr::as.quoted("cols := ...")` and then wrap in eval like `x[, eval(f(c("x3","x4")))]`. Likely to be extended to accept symbols and build expression on language objects.

Answer (score 2):

Just refer to the function by name:

```
myfun <- "mean"
x[,paste(names(x),myfun,sep="_"):=lapply(.SD,myfun)]
#    x1 x2 x1_mean x2_mean
# 1:  1  1       3       3
# 2:  2  2       3       3
# 3:  3  3       3       3
# 4:  4  4       3       3
# 5:  5  5       3       3
```

Customization is straightforward:

```
divby2 <- function(x) x/2 # custom function
myfun  <- "divby2"
mycols <- "x1"            # custom columns
x[,paste(mycols,myfun,sep="_"):=lapply(.SD,myfun),.SDcols=mycols]
#    x1 x2 x1_mean x2_mean x1_divby2
# 1:  1  1       3       3       0.5
# 2:  2  2       3       3       1.0
# 3:  3  3       3       3       1.5
# 4:  4  4       3       3       2.0
# 5:  5  5       3       3       2.5
```

We may some day have syntax like `paste(.SDcols,myfun,sep="_"):=lapply(.SD,myfun)`, but `.SDcols` on the left-hand side is not supported currently.

---

**Making a function.** If you want a function to do this, there's

```
add_myfun <- function(DT,myfun,mycols){
  DT[,paste(mycols,myfun,sep="_"):=lapply(.SD,myfun),.SDcols=mycols]
}
add_myfun(x,"median","x2")
```

Can a function be written that will work inside `j` of `DT[i,j]`? Maybe. But I think it's not a good idea.

1. Can you be sure your function will be robust to all the other uses of `j`, like `by`?
2. Can your function take advantage of `data.table`'s optimization (e.g., of `mean`)?
3. Will anyone else be able to read your code?
4. Using `[` can be slow. If you're doing this for many columns, you might be better off initializing the new columns and assigning with `set`.

Comment: I think OP already knows all that and looks for something entirely different, But I may be wrong.

Comment: Maybe so. It wasn't clear to me from the post that they know the idiom. Actually implementing a function like `MEAN(x1,x2)` would make the code illegible to anyone else and seems like a bad idea...

Comment: You could easily do something like `MEAN <- function(...){
  l <- list(...);
  lapply(l, mean)
};

x[, MEAN(x1,x2)]`. You could also add a `FUN` argument and call this function albit different and make it more general. The main problem is to how to wrap `:=` in there.

Comment: Is there a way to combine David's suggested function with what Frank wrote about making a function? Suppose I wanted to write `MEAN(x, col1, col2)` where `x` is a `data.table` and `col1` and `col2` are columns (note they are unquoted). Forgetting about the assignment for a second, my first thought was `MEAN <- function(x, ...) { x[, lapply(list(...), mean)] }` but that will fail with a `object col1 not found` error, as it apparently doesn't evaluate `list(...)` within the `x` environment. This would be nice as I could do things like `MEAN(x, col2, col3=col1+col2)`

Comment: Commenting on my previous comment: The very last sentence is key, as I could do the simple `MEAN(x, col1, col2)` example by recovering the column names using `cols <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)` and then plugging those into `.SDcols` within the function. But I don't think I could handle the creation of new columns, as in `col3=col1+col2` using this method.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why would you have `col3=col1+col2` in a function called `MEAN`? What is that the mean of? Maybe @DavidArenburg has an idea. (Not sure if your comment pinged him.) I have used `...` maybe one time years ago and try to avoid eval/parse/substitute, so I'm out of my depth here.